# How do i move an object to the right using the arrow key right?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a script with a function Update inside:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The force which is added when the player jumps
    // This can be changed in the Inspector window
    public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 300);

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        // Jump
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(jumpForce);
        }
    }
}
```

It was working fine when i clicked the space bar button the object was jumping up then falling down.
Now i want that when i click on the right arrow key the object will move to the right so i did:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Update ()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

But now when i click the PLAY button in the unity program nothing happened i see a blink for second and that's it the game never run.

Comment: I see now when i'm trying to run my game i gett compiler error: Assets/Scripts/Player.cs(13,1): error CS8025: Parsing error when i click on it it's going to the Mono-Develop-Unity and line 13 there is just closing }

Comment: Ok i fixed the error needed to add another } closing to the script. But still when running the game now the object is just falling down why it's not moving to the right when i click the Up Arrow  key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vector3.forward` will move your object in the **Z axis** (kind of getting deeper), while you need your object to move right in the **X axis**. If you want your object to move right, use `Vector3.right`. Also it seems that you're making a 2D game, so `Vector2` is better in this case.

```
transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime);
```